# How to fix javascript not assigning correct values?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Im trying to store the last selected value that was less than `maxrange.value` and use it to change the slider value when its not true.
When the first value one changes to more than the second one I want it to go back to the last value that was lower than the second one.

```html
    <input id="slider-min" type="range" value="14" min="1" max="20" step="1" oninput="checkifvaluemin()"/>
    <input id="slider-max" type="range" value="16" min="1" max="20" step="1" oninput="checkifvaluemax()"/>
```

```
      var minrange = document.getElementById("slider-min");
      var maxrange = document.getElementById("slider-max");
        function checkifvaluemin() {
          if (minrange.value < maxrange.value) {
            var lastvaluemin = minrange.value;
            minrange.value = lastvaluemin;
          }
        }
        function checkifvaluemax() {
          if (minrange.value > maxrange.value) {
            var lastvaluemax = maxrange.value;
            maxrange.value = lastvaluemax;
        }
}
```

the `lastvaluemin` is skipping numbers 2-9

Comment: The `.value` of an input field will be a string. You need to convert it to a number before trying to compare it

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: @p.s.w.g This can be defeated if used as `.valueAsNumber`

Comment: Closing slash 'til the day I die (or 'til the day I use a template system instead of writing raw HTML).

Comment: @AndrewKoster The closing slash is not specified anywhere since the beginning of HTML, has no meaning, does nothing and browsers are instructed to ignore it. So including a closing slash is pointless in all cases.

Comment: HTML is weird and inconsistent, yeah. For other elements like <script>, you need to include an entire closing tag, even for an empty tag that just has a `src` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do want you want, if I understand your requirement.

What I changed:

- Added lots of logging so that we can see what is happening.
- Logged the min/max values as JSON so that we can tell whether they are strings or numbers.
- Converted the min/max values to integers using `parseInt` so that the comparison results make sense.
- The condition of your first `if` statement didn't make sense to me, so I reversed it.
- Inside both `if` statements, you were assigning the current value of the slider to itself. This will never have an effect. I changed it so that the slider is assigned the value of the other slider, which allows them to limit each other.

  ```
  <input id="slider-min" type="range" value="14" min="1" max="20" step="1" oninput="checkifvaluemin()"/>
  <input id="slider-max" type="range" value="16" min="1" max="20" step="1" oninput="checkifvaluemax()"/>

  <script>
      const minrange = document.getElementById("slider-min");
      const maxrange = document.getElementById("slider-max");

      function checkifvaluemin() {

          const min = parseInt(minrange.value);
          const max = parseInt(maxrange.value);

          console.log('min', JSON.stringify(min));
          console.log('max', JSON.stringify(max));

          if (min > max) {

              console.log('Checkifvaluemin min > max. Changing.');

              minrange.value = max;

          } else {

              console.log('Checkifvaluemin min <= max. Doing nothing.');
          }
      }

      function checkifvaluemax() {

          const min = parseInt(minrange.value);
          const max = parseInt(maxrange.value);

          console.log('min', JSON.stringify(min));
          console.log('max', JSON.stringify(max));

          if (min > max) {

              console.log('Checkifvaluemax min > max. Changing.');

              maxrange.value = min;

          } else {

              console.log('Checkifvaluemax min <= max. Doing nothing.');
          }
      }
  </script>
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure from the description provided by OP so I'll outline according to what *I think the OP question is.*

1. The minimum range input property `min` is always less than the `min` property  of the maximum range input.
2. The maximum range input property `max` is always more than the `max` property of the minimum range input.

In order to create this behavior we can use the `oninput` attribute to adjust the `min/max` properties. The values are displayed by `<output>` tags.

#### `<form>`

```
oninput=
// min range max property is at least 1 less than max range max property 
minIN.max = maxIN.valueAsNumber-1,
// max range min property is at least 1 more than min range min property
maxIN.min = minIN.valueAsNumber+1,
// displays the difference between min and max
minMax.value = maxIN.valueAsNumber - minIN.valueAsNumber
```

#### `<input type="range">`

```
oninput=
// The <output> of min and max ranges are synced to react when either one gets user input
// A poor man's two-way data-binding   
minOUT.value = this.value, 
maxOUT.value = maxIN.value
...
maxOUT.value = this.value, 
minOUT.value = minIN.value
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 16px/1.2 Consolas;
}

label,
input,
output {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  height: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

[type=range] {
  width: 28.5vw;
}

label b {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15vw;
}

.max {
  text-align: right;
}

.minMax {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<form id='ui' oninput='minIN.max = maxIN.valueAsNumber-1, maxIN.min = minIN.valueAsNumber+1, minMax.value = maxIN.valueAsNumber - minIN.valueAsNumber'>

  <label class='min' for='minIN'><b>MIN:
  <output id='minOUT' for='minIN'>14</output></b><br>
  
  <input id="minIN" type="range" value="14" min="1" max="19" step="1" oninput="minOUT.value = this.value, maxOUT.value = maxIN.value">
</label>

  <label class='minMax' for='minMax'><b>SIZE:
<output id='minMax' for='maxIN minIN'>2</output></b>
</label>

  <label class='max' for='maxIN'><b>MAX:
  <output id='maxOUT' for='maxIN'>16</output></b><br>
  
  <input id="maxIN" type="range" value="16" min="2" max="20" step="1" oninput="maxOUT.value = this.value, minOUT.value = minIN.value">
</label>

</form>
```